# Android code to make the Wi-Fi connection stable

Tags: android, performance, android-wifi

I am working on an android wear application which constantly get disconnected from the WiFi. Is there a way I could keep the WiFi connection stable programmatically? I know this more of a hardware issues, but I see some applications that helps in keeping the WiFi connection stable.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, that's a hardware issue. Best I can suggest is running whatever you can offline, then have online features catch up when connection becomes available

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcastreceiver to check Internet is connected or not like below.

Manifest.Java

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<!-- This permissions are neccessary for broadcast receiver -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name=".Receiver"
        android:enabled="true" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Intent filters for broadcast receiver -->
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

MyApplication.Java

public class MyApplication  extends Application {
    // Gloabl declaration of variable to use in whole app

```
public static boolean activityVisible; // Variable that will check the
// current activity state

public static boolean isActivityVisible() {
    return activityVisible; // return true or false
}

public static void activityResumed() {
    activityVisible = true;// this will set true when activity resumed

}

public static void activityPaused() {
    activityVisible = false;// this will set false when activity paused

}
```

}

Receiver.Java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.util.Log;

/**
 * Created by root on 7/4/17.
 */
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        try {

            boolean isVisible = MyApplication.isActivityVisible();// Check if
            // activity
            // is
            // visible
            // or not
            Log.i("ActivityVisible ", "visible : " + isVisible);

            // If it is visible then trigger the task else do nothing
            if (isVisible == true) {
                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager
                        .getActiveNetworkInfo();

                // Check internet connection and accrding to state change the
                // text of activity by calling method
                if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                    new MainActivity().changeTextStatus(true);
                    Log.i("ActivityVisible ", "visible : " + isVisible);
                } else {
                    new MainActivity().changeTextStatus(false);
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

MainActivity.Java

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static TextView internetStatus;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        internetStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.internet_status);

        // At activity startup we manually check the internet status and change
        // the text status
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            changeTextStatus(true);
        } else {
            changeTextStatus(false);
        }
    }
    // Method to change the text status
    public void changeTextStatus(boolean isConnected) {

        // Change status according to boolean value
        if (isConnected) {
            internetStatus.setText("Internet Connected.");
            internetStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00ff00"));
        } else {
            internetStatus.setText("Internet Disconnected.");
            internetStatus.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {

        super.onPause();
        MyApplication.activityPaused();// On Pause notify the Application
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();
        MyApplication.activityResumed();// On Resume notify the Application
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not trying to get notified on wifi disconnection. Is there a way like a service that works on holdng the wifi connection.

Comment: what u need excatly?